# Windows won't start with new 2x4GB RAM on Asus P5Q

Tags: memory, motherboard

I bought two new DDR2 2x4GB non-ECC, un-buffered ram sticks from ebay. Here is [product link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/162578705162).

After installing them on my [Asus P5Q](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5Q/specifications/),
I got blue screen error once I reached windows boot screen. After few tries computer stops at bios start. I have Windows 10 1709 on my PC. Then I removed ram sticks and realized that they are more heated than my old ram sticks.

Please can anyone help me to fix this or give me some advise? Thank.

[image: RAM]

Comment: Grab a free copy of memtest. Boot to that and see if it passes. It's the only way to be sure: https://www.memtest86.com/

Comment: How many sticks are you using total? Just the new ones that you got?

Comment: @DrZoo I tried all ways. like put new one stick, both new sticks, new one stick and old 1 gb 800mhz stick, new stick and old 2 gb 667mhz stick... nothing happened.. :(

Comment: @HackSlash I tested with that software you mentioned.. Its freezed.. :( .. Whats this means...? https://imgur.com/a/GYdCf

Comment: That is the test screen. It should be rolling. Numbers changing. If it froze then you know you have a hardware problem. Might be bad RAM or bad CPU. If you know the CPU is good then that only leaves one thing....

Comment: @HackSlash Then i tried one by one.. here is the result... https://imgur.com/a/nZGH2 :( ... what is this error..?

Comment: I don't see anything in that link. Check it yourself.

Comment: @HackSlash yah sorry dear my bad... please check this one.. https://ibb.co/cm1Rpx

Comment: Yup, those are memory errors. You have bad RAM. Return that to the seller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the RAM is bad. This was verified using MEMTEST86.

Comment: @guest I'm not sure that is a real thing that has ever existed. Besides, that memory is on the QVL for his Intel MB. So it is supported.

Comment: @guest thanks for the comment friend.. But i think sellers labeled this as "only for amd" because of that non ecc and un buffered thing. And also i think intel motherboard means original intel motherboard.. This one is Asus and this motherboard requires non ecc unbuffered ram. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you bought are refurbished/recycled RAM chips by obscure Chinese OEM.

The Samsung sticker is fake, along with the claimed part number, which happens to be included in the QVL of memory for P5Q, likely to mislead people into buying it.

If you read the marking on the black chips of your RAM, you will find "SEC **XXX** HCE6", with chips having different XXX values. On genuine Samsung it should be the same value, eg. 816, which corresponds to the 0816 as shown on the sticker, to indicate it is manufactured in the 16th week of year 2008. Also, HC**E6** means it's rated as DDR2-667, so it is falsely advertised as DDR2-800.

This RAM is advertised as AMD-only for a reason: it is of 2Rx4. Consumer motherboard with Intel chipset only support 1Rx8/2Rx8/1Rx16.
If this is hard to understand and believe, think this way: if you are the seller, would you slander your products capable of supporting multiple platforms (in this case, AMD & Intel) as AMD-only and sell at a lower price?

Comment: This is not really an answer I would like to submit. It is incomplete and need further research and polishing. Posting this prematurely in hope of keeping OP informed of his purchase.

Comment: Related: [Is 'AMD-only' RAM really restricted to AMD chipsets](https://superuser.com/q/1048215/)