# When did Intel start supporting "high density RAM / memory" & will the Core i7-3770 support it?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, intel-core-i7, am3

I have multiple HP Compaq Elite 8300 CMT (with Core i7-3770 processors) workstations that accept DDR3-1600 (PC3-12800) memory. I was about to order some memory of this specification: "(4x8GB) DDR3-1600 PC3-12800 240 PIN DIMM RAM For AMD AM3 AM3+ Socket MB" but as you may note, it says that it's for an AMD board. Here is an image of the DIMM with its accompanying label (I underlined the "AMD Only" on the label):
[image: DIMM Picture]

I thought that this must be a marketing move, but then upon placing the order the seller contacted me to verify that I was ordering this for AMD and NOT Intel.

(Specifically this RAM is to be for this [HP Compaq Elite 8300 CMT with a Core i7-3770 @ 3.4 GHz](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03343457#AbT4).)

As per this question: ["Can 'AMD-only' RAM really restricted to AMD chipsets, and if so, why?"](https://superuser.com/questions/1048215/can-amd-only-ram-really-restricted-to-amd-chipsets-and-if-so-why), my own question of whether or not this specific processor (apparently memory addressing moved to the CPU mid 2000s) will support this "HIGH DENSITY RAM" appears to have an answer that's just a big "***MAYBE***".

For example, in the [actual answer](https://superuser.com/a/1071182/103907), it's noted that Intel began supporting high density RAM at some point. The problem is that there doesn't seem to be 1) any detail on when this support began and 2) if BIOS updates or processor microcode updates at any point provided necessary support for any Intel chipsets / CPUs that did not previously have support.

And so we return full circle:

*When did Intel start supporting "high density RAM / memory" & will the Core i7-3770 support it?*

Comment: Please note how I've updated this question so as to no longer be a duplicate, but rather to request additional specific information that goes beyond the question that was the determined duplicate.