# MSI H61M-P21 (B3) and DDR3 1600mhz issue

Tags: motherboard, ddr3

I installed i5-3570s proc to H61M-P21 (B3) motherboard, but 1600mhz ddr3 isn't working (3 beeps from speaker).
In a manual I have found that 1600mhz ddr3 should work with Ivy Bridge processors.
https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/H61MP21_B3/Specification

What I am doing wrong?

Upd.
This RAM I tried to use was a "special AMD only" RAM.
[Can 'AMD-only' RAM really be restricted to AMD chipsets, and if so, why?](https://superuser.com/questions/1048215/can-amd-only-ram-really-be-restricted-to-amd-chipsets-and-if-so-why)
i5-3570s proc on H61M-P21 (B3) motherboard with 1600mhz DDR3 works fine.

Comment: Do you have more than one stick?  Do you have any other ram you can try?

Comment: What makes you think that your RAM is not faulty?  That is what 3 beeps means after all...

Comment: This RAM replaced from worked PC.

Comment: I am betting you are going to need to do a process of elimination.  Try another slot, try another stick, etc.  Just because a manufacturer SAYS that something works.. they don't always.

Comment: Looks like I've found where is the clue. Inspecting this memory I recognized as "AMD special" RAM and beautifully worked on AMD PC. Now I successfully upgraded RAM with another brand ranks and got i5-3570s connected to 1600mhz memory. So, moral is: not every RAM is same.

Comment: Yes, Señor CMasMas, I did elimination. Tried to adjust all RAM settings... Thank you a lot!